# Non-cosemisimple duals of pointed Hopf algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

I take the following quote from an answer to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86627/what-is-a-pointed-hopf-algebra)

> A Hopf algebra is called **pointed** if all its simple left (or right)
> comodules are one-dimensional. The quantized enveloping algebras and
> Lusztig's small quantum groups are examples of pointed Hopf algebras.

The finte/restricted Hopf duals of quantized enveloping algebras are all cosemisimple. Does this happen in general, or are the duals of all pointed Hopf algebras cosemisimple?

Answer (score 4):

No way, doc! Take a finite $p$-group $G$. Let ${\mathbb F}$ be a field of characteristic $p$. The group algebra ${\mathbb F}G$ is as pointed as it gets. But its dual ${\mathbb F}G^{\ast}$ is not cosemisimple because ${\mathbb F}G$ is not semisimple.